# M 2.2 - Swagger UI gives undefined and Request does not match any route

Tags: magento2.2, api, swaggerui

Failed to load API definition.
undefined https://www.example.com/rest/default/schema?services=all

While inspecting further i can see that it gives me below error.

```
{message: "Request does not match any route.", trace: null}
message: "Request does not match any route."
trace: null
```

**Few other points**

- Website has SSL on
- Developer mode is on
- JS and CSS merging is off for now

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this?

Comment: As 2.2 was deprecated so thought better to upgrade Magento version, now its showing fine with Magento 2.4 version.